I want to fetch distinct data from the system
As shown in Image I want to fetch distinct data. But due to different stage it is showing number of records. Please help me

select distinct(d._System_objNBS)
, d._System_CurrentStage
, d.CreatedDate
, d.dateModified
, d.fld016535 as Originator_Dept
, e.fld004216
, e.fld003984 
from Obj122 d 
full join Obj81 e on d.UserCreatedId=e.UserId 
where d._System_CurrentStage NOT IN ('Release') 
and d.dateModified < '2024-06-30'

I have written above code

Help us help you - share the result you're trying to get and the [tag:rdbms] you're using

Please do not use images... Use table markdown

Please share your desired output.
If one record exists in multiple stages, what is your preferred output?

Do you maybe want to GROUP BY that d._System_objNBS?

distinct isn't a function, it's a set quantifier. select distinct will give you distinct rows. Skip those extra parentheses, and simply write select distinct d._System_objNBS, d._System_CurrentStage ... to make code clearer.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Probably select distinct isn't what you need.

If you want to get distinct value of d._System_objNBS, you'd better use Group by.
your query returns distinct value of all columns. your first and second row are different in date_modified. so it is reasonable that you get 2 duplicated record in _System_objNBS.
You can write query in this way:
select d._System_objNBS, 
       AGGREGATE_FUNCTION( d.other_columns)
from Obj122 d 
full join Obj81 e on d.UserCreatedId=e.UserId
 where d._System_CurrentStage NOT IN ('Release') 
 and d.dateModified < '2024-06-30'
GROUP BY d._System_objNBS

notice that you should use the best aggregate_function (sum, min, max, etc.) for each column that is  not in your GROUP BY.
